# How to use custom version table instead of version table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, paper-trail-gem

For a project I'm currently working on I need to implement object versioning. Unfortunately I need to keep a full history of each object, so a single table solution like Papertrail would quickly become un-manageable. So I am trying to have custom version table for each object using papertrail. I followed the documentation but getting error on creating object

> Model::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'event' for ArticleVersion.

Here is the implemented code :

```
  class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_paper_trail class_name: 'ArticleVersion'
  end

  class ArticleVersion < PaperTrail::Version
   self.table_name = :article_versions
  end

  module PaperTrail
   class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
     include PaperTrail::VersionConcern
     self.abstract_class = true
   end
  end
```

Here is the migration for Article migrations:

```
class CreateArticleVersions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
  create_table :article_versions do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.text :text

  t.timestamps
end
end
end
```

and When I am trying to create article by Article.create(text:'some text')
I am getting the above mentioned error.
Can anyone help me to figure out if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
create_table :article_versions do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.text :text
  t.timestamps
end

Model::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'event' for ArticleVersion.
```

The `ArticleVersion` **model** lacks an `event` **attribute** because the `article_versions` **table** lacks an `event` **column**.